Right angle chamfer where only the outer edge is an arc
I'm trying to recreate the chamfer on the picture below. I've spent hours searching here and youtube but I can't find an option that allows me to get to the same result. Any idea?
Thanks in advance.


Not possible in Blender! Edges can't be curved lines.

It appears the software pictured is using some virtual geometry to create the additional faces needed to correctly shade that corner.  In Blender you will more than likely have to deal with the real geometry

from my experience you actually don't want a right angle like that - you want a normal arc, but on the outer side you want it to be big (like on the picture), and on the inner side you want it to be very small. This will produce 'good' shading and work well with other parts of Blender workflow like subdivision surface. But I understand: there are various use-cases e.g. video games.

You can achieve such bevel with bezier curve objects.
You must first fillet the vertex to get a rounded corner like say using the Extension Curve Tools using the Fillet function, or a dedicated extension like Bezier Curve Fillet.
The fillet corner radius must have exactly the same dimension as de desired chamfer size .
Then under the bezier curve object Object Data properties, use the Geometry > Extrude to add thickness, then the Bevel > Depth to make the chamfer.
Reduce the Resolution to 0. You may optionally want to add an Edge Split modifier for best shading results.

